# Change font-size or div class depending on language selected

Tags: jquery, html, css, nav

I have a horizontal navigation centered in the page with logo and content. On the page it has language translations such as english (default), french, russian and german. When you click on these links the text on the website changes.

My only issue is when the language is changed from english to russian or german, the text on the navigation breaks to another line as words are longer (its ok for content just want the navigation on one line!). This is not attractive and i cant have the text right across the page as there is a styling each side and a border-top which the text must stay within.

My only solution is to change the padding/font-size depending on the languauge selected? (unless anyone knows a better solution).

I can only think to create some kind of jQuery function that will detect what language is active (as the language list has a class of active when selected) and then depending on the language change or add css styling to the nav class?

Hope anyone can help me in the right direction or any links on relavent information.

I will put my html and css markup/demo in here but may not be any help:

html example:

```
<div id = "navigation">
   <ul class "nav">
      <li> <a href...... class="active">link</a></li>
   <ul>
</div>
```

my language list is basically nearly set out the same as the menu in the top corner.

css:

```
.nav {
    width:80%;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-width:1px 0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:auto;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}

.nav li{
    display:inline;
}
.nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could assign a unique language class to your `<body>` tag, and use that to apply a specific style to your nav based off of the language selected.

Example:

```
<body class="language-english">...
```

Then for the CSS...

```
.language-english .nav { font-size: 12px; }
```

You could also account for the longer translated text, and make your navigation more dynamic/fluid to accommodate for varying text lengths.

Answer (score 0):

And the jQuery solution:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {    
        $('#navigation a').on('click', function() { 
          if( $(this).attr('href') == 'russian' || $(this).attr('href') == 'german') {
            $('.nav').css('fontSize', '11px');
          };
        });
    })
```

Change the strings 'russian' and 'german' according the href attributes.